# Contract design pattern widely used android

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I have noticed that developers of default apps for Android use Contract pattern. It is often used databases, content providers. Contract class is final and stores constants, and weird thing for me is inner interfaces.

```
public final class ClockContract 
protected interface AlarmsColumns extends AlarmSettingColumns, BaseColumns
protected interface InstancesColumns extends AlarmSettingColumns, BaseColumns 
protected interface CitiesColumns
```

All this classes (and interfaces) is container for constants. Is it good approach to do like this. Why not to define them in each class ?
And is it good practice to store variables in interfaces.
And the most weir thing for me is the puprose of inner interfaces . Please explain the idea of this.
Thanks

Comment: Read up on the idea in Content Providers: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html

Answer (score 0):

A contract is basically a list of definitions used for a group of specified purposes. It is a good practice because people will not likely misuse all the classes and interfaces in unrelated domains.

```
public final class DatabaseContract {
/***Inner class that defines the table contents.***/
public static abstract class Entry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String
            TABLE_NAME = "Alarms",
            COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_DAY = "day",
            COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_HOUR = "hour",
            COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_MINUTE = "minute",
            COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_STATUS = "status",
            COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ALARM_TEXT = "alarmtext";
}

private DatabaseContract(){}

public static void init(Context context){
    new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

public static Cursor selectAll(Context context){
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    return new DatabaseHelper(context).getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql,null);
}

public static void insert(Context context, ContentValues values){
    new DatabaseHelper(context).getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}

public static void update(Context context, int id, ContentValues values){
    new DatabaseHelper(context).getWritableDatabase().update(TABLE_NAME, values, Entry._ID + " = " + id, null);
}

public static void remove(Context context, int id){
    new DatabaseHelper(context).getWritableDatabase().delete(TABLE_NAME, Entry._ID + " = " + id, null);
}}
```

The code above is an example of contract pattern. It is obvious to see that you won't use the inner class Entry anywhere else but accessing database. It is just like you create an enumeration to support your class where you might want to limit the input parameters for class functions.

If you don't need to deal with multi access to the variable, you can store variable in contract. However, it is not supposed to do because contract is mean to store definitions and protocols. Those things aren't supposed to be changed during run time.